# Calculating the worst outcome from a list of values

Tags: javascript

Given an array of severity from an external risk management system

```
const severities = [
  { value: 'minor', enumFieldOptions: [{ value: 'catastrophic' }, { value: 'major' }, { value: 'minor' }] },
  undefined,
  { value: 'catastrophic', enumFieldOptions: [{ value: 'catastrophic' }, { value: 'major' }, { value: 'minor' }] },
  { value: 'major', enumFieldOptions: [{ value: 'catastrophic' }, { value: 'major' }, { value: 'minor' }] },
]
```

- a single severity might be undefined
- each severity has a `value` and `enumFieldOptions` containing all possible options
- all `enumFieldOptions` are equal ( same items, exact same order, starting from worst )

Based on that data I want to calculate the worst severity. For this data I would expect the outcome `catastrophic`, but it might return `undefined` if the array is empty or all severities are `undefined`.

I started with the following approach

```js
const severities = [
  { value: 'minor', enumFieldOptions: [{ value: 'catastrophic' }, { value: 'major' }, { value: 'minor' }] },
  undefined,
  { value: 'catastrophic', enumFieldOptions: [{ value: 'catastrophic' }, { value: 'major' }, { value: 'minor' }] },
  { value: 'major', enumFieldOptions: [{ value: 'catastrophic' }, { value: 'major' }, { value: 'minor' }] },
]

const { value } = severities.reduce((severityResult, currentSeverity) => {
  if (!currentSeverity) {
    return severityResult;
  }
  
  let currentSeverityIndex = currentSeverity.enumFieldOptions.findIndex(severity => severity.value === currentSeverity.value);

    if(currentSeverityIndex === -1) {
      currentSeverityIndex = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  }
  
  if(currentSeverityIndex < severityResult.index) {
      return { value: currentSeverity.value, index: currentSeverityIndex }
  }
  
  return severityResult;
}, { value: undefined, index: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY });

console.log(value);
```

Performance is very critical and maybe this code can be optimized.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the point of `enumFieldOptions` if it's the same for all entries?

Comment: I can't tell you, this is the data I'm receiving from an external API

Comment: do `enumFieldOptions` ever change or is it always the same?

Comment: A user might change the enumeration in the external system so it will respond with a different array